# Determine solder ball size

Tags: soldering

I have ps4 stencils for ps4 APU. On the stencil it says 0.55.
Can I asume that the solder ball size is 0.55 or can I go with 0.5?

How can I determine the correct solder ball size for the bga chip? (Any chip)

Thanks! :)

Comment: where does what say what, exactly?

Comment: What stencil, what are you trying to do? Making a footprint? Ordering solder balls? Re-balling a BGA?

Comment: I've updated the question. Thanks for reaponding, hope it will be more clear now. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The.55 is probably the pitch (distance between solder balls) Find the spec sheet for the component, you will find the ball diameter and all the mechanical measurements.

Comment: I can't find anything on the PS4 APU chip that shows what ball size do I need.
Is there anyway to tell the ball size by the stencil?
What happen if it's needed a 0.55 ball size and I use 0.50 or 0.45?